# Twilio Flow Send and Wait for Reply using a Content template SID: deliveryFailure

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I've been working on a simple appointment reminder flow in Twilio Studio and it has worked great, until I decided to use a content template specifying the Template SID:

[image]

The specified content template has been approved already, and the flow was working through whatsapp properly before using a custom message rather than with the content template.

In the flow log there's a deliveryFailure error when launching the flow with the following output:

```
To: whatsapp:+57xxxxx
From: whatsapp:+14xxxxx
Content Sid: HX9f1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content Variables: {"1":xxxx, "2": xxxxxxxx}
Failure sending message: A text message body or media urls must be specified.
```

It's worth to mention again that the content template has been already sent to Meta and it's approved to be used:

[image]

Any guidance on this matter will be appreciated, since the error is quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the awesome Twilio Support Team, they pointed out the issue with my flow. It ended up being a mistake on my side when triggering the execution of the Flow via a REST API. For the Send and Wait for Reply widget to work properly you need:

1. A Messaging Service associated with a Number and its ID: `MG32xxxxxxxxxxxxx`:

[image]

2. In the Messaging Service, under the integration area, in the incoming messages section, select **Send a Webhook** and paste the webhook URL of your Flow (you can obtain this from the Trigger Widget of the Flow):

[image]

3. In the Send and Wait For Reply widget you need to change the **Send message from** parameter to the MessagingServiceSID:

[image]

So after triggering the flow execution via API REST and changing the `From` parameter to use the Messaging Service SID instead of the number, it worked perfectly. I'm using PHP to trigger the Flow, so my code looks like this:

```php
<?php

$to = 'whatsapp:+57xxxxxxxxx';

// Important: the $from number below should be changed to be MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID
// instead of the number that is being used in the messaging service.
// This was causing the issue!
// $from = 'whatsapp:+1xxxxxx';
$from = 'MG32xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$messageData = array(
    'To' => $to,
    'From' => $from,
    'Parameters' => json_encode(array(
        'parameter1' => 'value1',
        'parameter2' => 'value2',
        'parameter3' => 'value3'
    ))
);

$flow = "FWfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

triggerFlowExecution("https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/$flow/Executions");
```

It's not easy to deduct this, specially when you're new with the Twilio Tools, but hope this helps someone using the same widget in Twilio Studio.